# How do I plot a simple bar chart with python and seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to do a bar chart using python and seaborn, but I am getting a error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'total'.
```

This is what I am trying to transform in a bar chart:

```
level_1     1900    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018
total        0.0    154.4   490.9   628.4   715.2   601.5
```

This is a image of the same dataframe:

[image: data frame]

Also I want to delete the column `1990`, but when I try to do it by deleting the index, the column `2014` is deleted.

I got this far until now:

```
valor_ano = sns.barplot(
    data= valor_ano,
    x= ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'],
    y= 'total')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

valor_ano = pd.DataFrame({'level_1':[1900, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018], 
                         'total':[0.0, 154.4, 490.9, 628.4,715.2,601.5]})

valor_ano.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)

valor_plot = sns.barplot(
    data= valor_ano,
    x= 'level_1',
    y= 'total')
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: Seaborn plot]

**EDIT:** If you want to do it without the dataframe and just pass in the raw data you can do it with the following code. You can also just use a variable containing a list instead of hard-coding the list:

```
valor_graph = sns.barplot(
    x= [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
    y= [154.4, 490.9, 628.4,715.2,601.5])
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, is there a way to do it without having to past the column and row values in the dataframe ? I am asking this because I want to automatize the production of these charts.

Comment: Well, the question then is how are you automating it? Are you reading in these values that you want to create charts from from a file? In that case you can still read them into a dataframe programmatically and generate charts from them as normal. Your question requires more information to answer.

Comment: Hi Mihai, I am a beginner with python, I am sorry for the lack of information. 

I reshaped and pivoted  from a csv file until I got the this dataframe that I am trying to transform in a barchart. 

I saved this dataframe in a variable called  "soma_ano_valor", and I am trying to do a script that everytime I load a new csv file the script produce the soma_ano_valor barchart.

Please let me know if there any other information necessary. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Well if that's the case, as long as you can get that `soma_ano_valor` dataframe variable created properly, all you have to do is run the plot code I had in the first code block and pass in the column names you have in your data frame as the `x` and `y` arguments, like I did with `level_1` and 'total`. Then seaborn will use those columns as the x and y on the bar chart. Just make sure you pass that dataframe in the call to `sns.barplot()` as `data=soma_valor_ano` and you're good to go.

Comment: I think I did something wrong with the dataframe.
It is not finding the level_1 index:
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'level_1'
I will try to redo the dataframe in another way so I can do the graphs.. Thanks a lot!